# How to set a property initialized by @PropertySource

Tags: spring

I need to set some properties in relation to an admin interface.
This is how I initialized the `@PropertySource`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MainConfig
```

Now, in my Admin Controller I need to set some properties from `application.properties`:

```
public @Controller @RequestMapping("admin") class AdminController {
    private @Autowired Environment env;

    public @RequestMapping(value = "settings.html", method = RequestMethod.POST) String processSettings(@Valid SettingsForm settingsForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return settings(model);
        }

        // env.setProperty("foo.bar", settingsForm.getFooBar());
        return "redirect:settings.html";
    }
}
```

But there's no `setProperty` method for `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`.
What I need to do to set those properties? Do I need to create another `@Bean`? How the `@Bean` should look like (without mention `application.properties` again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Environment` implementation classes register instances of `MutablePropertySources` in some specified order. When a property needs to be resolved from the `Environment`, it iterates (in order) through these `MutablePropertySources` and uses the first property value it finds.

Short of getting all the `MutablePropertySources` objects, iterating through them, finding the one corresponding to your `application.properties` file (or other), getting its name, and replacing it with a new `PropertySource` object with the changed value, there is no way to do this.

Note also that Spring creates a `PropertiesPropertySource` object for `.properties` files and it does not provide a method to change property values.

Comment: Then I need to use another way in my backend and `Environment` in my frontend.